# Dynamic Word autocomplete or autosuggest in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, add-in

Has anyone come across a VBA (or other) program for implementing dynamic autocomplete in Word? Emacs has had this for decades, and it would be great to have it in Word. I see others in this forum are looking for code for Android, so this topic isn't completely obscure. It would be great to type ac* - and get Word to fill in "across" based on previous text.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly both [Openoffice](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Word_Completion) and [MS Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/turn-on-or-off-autocomplete-HP005189585.aspx) has some sort of Auto-complete. I don't often use word processor though, but I hope it helps.

Comment: they have auto-complete, but it's not dynamic. auto-complete only completes words and phrases that have been entered previously.

Comment: I see. So basically you want a (VBA) script to fill up the Auto-complete list using the content of the current document?

Comment: Sort of. It's more of an auto-expand capability. For example, having just written the previous sentence, I could type cap<ctrl-e> (or similar) and "cap" would expand to "capability." If more than one work had the same start, for example w<ctrl-e> gives me written and would, I would choose which I wanted. Emacs had this, as does WinEdt, and it's a fantastic time saver. I don't want to populate the auto-complete list with every word in the document. Rather, I would create an array of words, I suppose, from the document and VBA would find which starting letters match what I've written so far.

Comment: Any news about this? have you found something useful?